# Flux and application state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm a bit confused about the Flux architecture, especially about the following statement:

> Application state is maintained only in the stores, allowing the
>   different parts of the application to remain highly decoupled.

I have a component which must have a state. My question is, if I want to use Flux in my application, **should this state live in the stores or inside the component?** Notice that this state is not data from an API.

Also, if an user performs an action, **should the component manage that action or an action creator?**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

A component gets its initial state from the store, but whenever the store emits a change, the state of the component is updated.

The tutorial on tylermcginnis.com broke it down quite well for me: http://tylermcginnis.com/reactjs-tutorial-pt-3-architecting-react-js-apps-with-flux/

Comment: Hi frogbandit, thanks for your response. I understand the Flux lifecycle. What I don't understand is when to use it. I mean, if I my component must have state, should this state go inside a store or in the component? The same goes for the action creators: should ALL the actions pass through an action creator or the component can manage a couple of them?

Comment: I'm still new to this as well, but following the process outlined in the tutorial, I believe the state should go in the component. And I don't think it's required that all items go through an actions module, but I think it is good practice.